# Packages loaded into memory

Tags: r, parallel-processing, package

I'm want to loop through all packages I have currently loaded in memory i.e. those I have "libraried", and export them to parallel clusters using

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(*pkagename*))
```

Is there a way of detecting which packages are loaded into memory and creating a list of them?

Comment: try `searchpaths()` or `loadedNamespaces()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find loaded packages:

```
(.packages())
```

Store them in a list:

```
l <- list(.packages())
```